# Удаление маркаров

Tags: google-maps-api

Помогите разобраться.
Читаю координаты маркера из PHP файла. Вывожу на карту.
Хочу удалить по нажатию на кнопку.
Вот мой код

```
    <body>
<div id="floating-panel">
<input onclick="clearMarkers();" type=button value="Remove line">
<input onclick="showMarkers();" type=button value="Restore line">
</div>
<div id="cities"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }
        function doNothing() {}

  function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.8029212, 37.7898788),
  zoom: 14,
  maxZoom: 20, // for max zoom
  minZoom: 12, // for min zoom
  scaleControl: true,
  mapTypeControl: true,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
 fullscreenControl: false,
 streetViewControl: false,
 });
           var image = {
          tp1: {
          url: './image/tp1.png',scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)},
          tp0: {
          url: './image/tp0.png',scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)},
};
           downloadUrl('phpsqlinfo_addrow.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');

                var icon = image[type] || {};              
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: icon,
                map: map,
                position: point,
              });
 markers.push(marker);
            });
          });
        }
    function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }

      function clearMarkers() {
      setMapOnAll(null);
      }
      function showMarkerl() {
      setMapOnAll(map);
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: `function setMapOnAll(...) { }` - ??

Comment: функцию вродь прописала, а все равно не получается